# Using cython to cross compile project from intel ubuntu to arm

Tags: python, gcc, cross-compiling, cython

I have simple python + cython project (hello world example from http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) on my ubuntu 16 x86_64. I can build this project with cython for x86_64.

How can I build the project for armv7 version of ubuntu 15 without using real armv7 board/cpu?

I have `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` (http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf) and it can compile simple C programs for armv7. How can I change settings of cython to use cross compiler for building shared objects for arm?

Comment: It might be easier to run a Ubuntu armhf installation in a virtual machine. qemu should support armv7, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/QemuARMVexpress

Comment: JJ, can I do this without full virtual machine installation?

Comment: It is possible to create a directory containing armhf installation (approximately 200 MiB) and then chroot to that directory (or schroot). [QEMU/Debootstrap approach](https://wiki.debian.org/EmDebian/CrossDebootstrap#QEMU.2Fdebootstrap_approach)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Architecture dependent libraries and headers files are needed for cross compiling.

When testing if python3.5-dev package and others could be installed after `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` and `apt-get update` (after some modification to sources.list), the result was basically.

```
python3.5-dev:armhf : Depends: python3.5:armhf (= 3.5.1-10) but it is not going to be installed
```

`apt-get install python3.5:armhf` is something that doesn't work, [see](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch)

> The existing proposals allow for the co-installation of libraries and
>   headers for different architectures, but not (yet) binaries.

One possible solution that does not require "full" virtual machine is provided by QEMU and chroot. A suitable directory for chroot can be created by `debootstrap` command. After creation, `schroot` can give access to that environment.

Substitute `<DIRECTORY>` and `<USER>` in the following commands:

```
apt-get install -y debootstrap qemu-user-static binfmt-support schroot
debootstrap --arch=armhf --foreign --include=gcc,g++,python3.5-dev xenial <DIRECTORY>
cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static <DIRECTORY>/usr/bin
chroot <DIRECTORY>
/debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
echo "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y cython cython3
exit
cat <<END > /etc/schroot/chroot.d/xenial-armhf
[xenial-armhf]
description=Ubuntu xenial armhf
type=directory
directory=/home/xenial-armhf
groups=sbuild,root
root-groups=sbuild,root
users=root,<USER>
END
```

The environment should be accessible by

```
schroot -c chroot:xenial-armhf
```

and for root user session (the user must be in a group listed in root-groups) ,

```
schroot -c chroot:xenial-armhf -u root
```

After this, it is also possible to cross compile a cython module:

hello.pyx:

```
print("hello world")
```

compiling (`python3.5-config --cflags` and `python3.5-config --libs` in chroot for options, note `-fPIC`):

```
cython hello.pyx
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --sysroot <DIRECTORY> -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c hello.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --shared --sysroot <DIRECTORY> -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm hello.o -o hello.so
```

The module can be then tested

```
schroot -c chroot:xenial-armhf
python3
import hello
```

Cross compiling cython based python modules may also work. With setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import os

os.environ['CC'] = 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'
os.environ['LDSHARED'] = 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared'
sysroot_args=['--sysroot', '/path/to/xenial-armhf']

setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules= [ Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"],
                                extra_compile_args=sysroot_args,
                                extra_link_args=sysroot_args) ])
```

Building a simple `hello world` module was possible this way. The file name for the module was wrong, in this case it was `hello.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. After renaming it as `hello.so` it was possible to import it.

Comment: Can I just unpack needed armhf deb packages into subdirectory and still use non-emulated (executed directly by native cpu) compiler which will output armhf binaries? My real project is bit larger than hello world, it has megabytes of "c" code and lot of c++ headers; emulated compiler will run for long time.

Comment: @osgx I hope this explains that [schroot](http://askubuntu.com/a/381527/493395) command

Comment: @osgx yes, compiling C/C++ code will be a lot slower with qemu. That environment built with `debootstrap` should be usable also for C/C++ cross-compilers (by adjusting library/include file paths) and installing additional dev-packages is possible with `apt-get install` after chroot. For python software that is built like `python setup.py build`, qemu/chroot solution should work much better. Cython-based modules are usually built like that, so I wrote my answer to accordingly

Comment: `python setup.py build` usually will build for host. How it can be instructed to build for cross system?

Comment: One way to cross compile is by setting CC and LD environment variables.  You need to install the cross-compiler and python dev package for your target architecture.
```python
import glob
imoport os
compiler_str = glob.glob('/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-[0-9]*')
os.environ['CC'] = compiler_str
os.environ['LDSHARED']  = compiler_str + ' -shared'
```