# How to use a different C++ compiler in Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython, distutils, cythonize

I'm working on a project to call C++ from Python. We use Cython for this purpose. When compile by using the command "python3.6 setup.py build_ext --inplace", the compiler "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc" is used. Is there a way to use a different compiler like "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++"?

Also, is there a way to add a compilation option such as "-DPLATFORM=linux"?

Here's the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
    "app",
    sources=["app.pyx", "myapp.cpp"],
    language="c++",
    include_dirs=["../base"]
)))
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388812/using-cython-to-cross-compile-project-from-intel-ubuntu-to-arm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell distutils to use gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the value of the `CC` environment variable in `setup.py`. For instance:

```
os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
```

or

```
os.environ["CC"] = "clang++"
```

Answer (score 2):

Distutils by default uses the `CC` system environment variable to decide what compiler to use. You can run the python script such that the `CC` variable is set to whatever you want at the beginning of the script before `setup()` is called.

As for passing flags to the compiler, add a `extra_compile_args` named argument to your `Extension()` module. It may look like this for example:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
    "app",
    sources=["app.pyx", "myapp.cpp"],
    language="c++",
    include_dirs=["../base"],
    extra_compile_args=["-DPLATFORM=linux"]
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify a C++ compiler for Cython, you need to set a proper `CXX` environment variable prior calling `setup.py`.

This could be done:

- Using a command-line option:

```
export CXX=clang++-10
```

- In the `setup.py`:

```
os.environ["CXX"] = "clang++-10"
```

Note: `clang++-10` is used as an example of the alternative C++ compiler.

Note: `CC` environment variable specifies C compiler, not C++. You may consider specifying also e.g. `export CC=clang-10`.