# PyCharm/Cython cross-compile on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, cython, cross-compiling

First, i have no experience with PyCharm and compilers. So maybe this is a funny question.

I have PyCharm Pro installed on Windows and I can cythonize *.py files to *.pyd with these instructions:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cython.html#cython-support

But, is it possible **from the same system** (pyCharm and Windows) cythonize with ARM compiler? I need cythonized files for ARMv71 device. Do I need to install ARMv compiler? How? Is this possible in the first place?

Forget to mention, I am working with python3.

Comment: PyCharm isn't a compiler, it's an IDE.

Comment: ok i know it is IDE, but it can produce cython file using the instructions I provided above, right?
So, instead *.pyd (pyd is for windows?) is it possible to cythonize binary for arm?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388812/using-cython-to-cross-compile-project-from-intel-ubuntu-to-arm

Comment: DavidW, my question is not related to your answer. I asked for pyCharm methods on Windows OS. You sending me to Ubuntu solution (how to cross compile on Ubuntu).
Key words: PyCharm, Windows. Please reopen my question. Thank you!

Comment: @CncMess I didn't close the question - I just posted a link that I thought might be relevant. Other people closed the question. Just because it isn't identical doesn't mean it's not related - if an answer exists I suspect it'll be *very* similar. Especially as the arm system you're compiling for is probably Linux too (this isn't clear)?